# Cycle removal process

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-graphs

Consider the following stochastic process for generating a forest: start from a complete graph on $n$ vertices and proceed to repeatedly remove the edges of uniformly chosen cycles. Formally, let $G_0$ denote the initial graph, and obtain $G_{i+1}$ from $G_i$ by selecting a cycle uniformly at random out of all cycles of $G_i$, regardless of their size, and removing all of its edges. The process ends when no cycles remain.

A few questions arise:

- What is the typical stopping time? Namely, estimate $\tau=\min\{i\mid G_i\text{ is a forest}\}$.
- What is the expected number of components in the resulting forest?
- Do we expect a "giant component" at the end of the process?